# Magento 2.1.1 Payment Gateway target URL

Tags: magento2

Im trying to make a new payment gateway in magento 2.1.1 that when a customer click on place order button he/she will be redirected to a third party url for example is `https://example_payment_carrier.com` and the custmer will complete his/her payment there. then after completing a payment the `https://example_payment_carrier.com` will bring him/her back to `https://example_mydomain.com/mygateway/paymentaction`

The question is where should I put the third party URL, so that when the place order button is clicked it will post a request including the form data to the third party carrrier?

Answer (score 2):

To create a redirected Payment gateway you need to create following files.
/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout paynow"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: continueToPaymentGateway,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/.js

```
    define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-method',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators'
    ],
    function ($, Component, setBillingAddressAction, setPaymentMethodAction,  additionalValidators) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: '<vendor_module>/payment/<paymentmethod>'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;
                this._super();

            },
            continueToPaymentGateway: function () {
                if (additionalValidators.validate()) {
                 //update payment method information if additional data was changed
                 this.selectPaymentMethod();

                 $.mage.redirect(window.checkoutConfig.payment.<paymentmethod>.redirectUrl);//or you can direct pass payment gateway url from here
                 return false;
               }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-method is no longer there in magento 2.1.1, $.mage.redirect(window.checkoutConfig.payment.<paymentmethod>.redirectUrl); is working good for me